# C# IUnityContainer resolve method

Tags: c#, unity-container, resolve

I've created a simple PRISM application with a standard bootstrapper inherited from UnityBootstrapper.

The UnityBootstrapper in turn has the public property IUnityContainer and this interface has the following resolve singature:

```
object Resolve(Type t, string name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
```

Now, I don't know how to get the other resolve methods which are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#ResolveObjects_Methods).

Am I confusing Unity with its IUnityContainer  interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Unity 1.2, `IUnityContainer` [had all of those overloads available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer.resolve.aspx).

In Unity 2.0, you need to bring [`UnityContainerExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextensions_members%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) in scope because the overloads you want are defined as extension methods on this class.

Answer (score 1):

`IUnityContainer` has the following resolve methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.iunitycontainer.resolve.aspx

Answer (score 1):

These methods are extension methods

Signature:

```
public static T Resolve<T>(this IUnityContainer container, params ResolverOverride[] overrides);
```

So if you have implemented `IUnityContainer` you can use them.